# In one dimensional calculus why is it that there is only one path between two points and how does this differ in multivariable calculus?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In trying to understand the difference between exact and inexact differential this seem to be a feature.  I am using the idea of "inexact differential" as defined in Wikipedia. To better  understand a gradient it may help me to understand what a gradient is not.

Comment: Your question seems quite broad.  Perhaps making it as precise as possible would be helpful

Comment: Actually, there are more than one path between two points in $\Bbb R$. For instance, here are three paths between $0$ and $1$: $$f(t)=t\\ g(t)=t^2\\ s(t)=\sin^2\left(\frac 72\pi t\right)$$

Comment: Yes It is stated in the first paragraph of Wikipedia. "inexact differential" . I didn't understand it either thus the motivation for the question in my never ending quest to understand the difference between the apparently well known term in mathematics of "exact differential" and the apparent mystery of "inexact".

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to understand the gradient, you need to first look at the linearization of a function $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ i.e $L(\textbf{x}) = f(\textbf{p}) + \nabla f(\textbf{p}) \cdot (\textbf{x} - \textbf{p})$ where $\textbf{p}$ is sufficiently close to $\textbf{x}$. Hence, $L(\textbf{x})$ is a linear approximation of $f(\textbf{x})$ near $\textbf{p}$ i.e $f(\textbf{x}) = f(\textbf{p}) + \nabla f(\textbf{p}) \cdot (\textbf{x} - \textbf{p}) + \epsilon(\textbf{x})$. Now if we let $\textbf{x}- \textbf{p} = \vec{h}$ then we see that the gradient has the following property,

$$\lim_{\vec{h} \to \textbf{0}} \frac{\| f(\textbf{p}) - f(\textbf{x}) - \nabla f(\textbf{p})\cdot \vec{h}\|}{\|\vec{h}\|} = 0$$

This gives us the exact motivation for the definition of the derivative. We define the derivative of a function $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ to be the linear map $Dg(\textbf{x})$ such that,

$$ \lim_{\vec{h} \to \textbf{0}} \frac{\| g(\textbf{x} + \vec{h}) - g(\textbf{x}) - Dg(\textbf{x}) \cdot \vec{h}\|}{\|\vec{h}\|} = 0$$

In the case where $m = 1$ then $Df(\textbf{p}) = \nabla f(\textbf{p})$ and so given $f = (f^1, \dots ,f^m)^T$ we can approximate each $f^i$ by $\nabla f^i$ and so it follows that,

$$ Df(\textbf{p}) = \begin{pmatrix} \nabla f^1(\textbf{p}) \\ \nabla f^2(\textbf{p}) \\ \vdots \\ \nabla f^m(\textbf{p}) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f^1}{\partial x^1}(\textbf{p}) & \cdots &  \frac{\partial f^1}{\partial x^n}(\textbf{p}) \\ \vdots \\ \frac{\partial f^m}{\partial x^1}(\textbf{p})& \cdots &  \frac{\partial f^m}{\partial x^n}(\textbf{p}) \end{pmatrix}$$

Observe now the big picture here. Nice functions have nice graphs which can approximated by tangent planes. Well, $Df(\textbf{p})$ is a linear map and so $\textbf{Im}(Df(\textbf{p}))+f(\textbf{p})$ is a plane at $f(\textbf{p})$.